# Computing $\lim_{z\to 2\pi i}\frac{z}{e^z-1}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

It's easy to see that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{e^z}=1.$$
But what about
$$\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 2\pi i}\frac{z}{e^z-1}?$$
The function $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, but has a pole at $z=2\pi i$ (why can't it be another removable singularity?). Why can't we use L'Hôpital's rule and plug in $z=2\pi i$ to $\frac{1}{e^z}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use l'Hôpital's because the result of substituting $2\pi i$ into the numerator is not $0$.

The function has a pole at $2\pi i$ because the denominator is zero and the numerator *non-zero* there.